# why are system calls handled using interrupts?

Tags: interrupt, system-calls, kernel

I have a basic question about the linux system call.
Why are the  system calls not handled just like normal function calls and why is handled via software interrupts?
Is it because, there is no linking process performed for user space application with kernel during the build process of user application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linking between separately compiled pieces of code is a minor problem. Shared libraries have had a workaround for it for quite some time (relocatable code, export tables, etc). You pay the cost typically just once, when you load the library in the program.

The bigger problem is that you need to switch the CPU from the unprivileged, user mode into the privileged, kernel mode and you need to do it in a controllable way, without letting user code escape and wreck a havoc on the kernel. And that's typically done with special or designated instructions. You may also benefit from automatic interrupt disabling when transitioning into the kernel, which the x86 `int` instruction can do for you. Most CPUs have something like this instruction and it's a common way of implementing the system call interface, although not the only one.

If you asked about MS-DOS or the original MINIX, both of which ran on the i8086 in the real address mode, where the kernel couldn't protect itself or other programs from anything because all the memory and system resources were accessible to all code, then there would be less reason in using a special instruction like `int`, there were no two modes, only one, and in that respect `int` would be largely equivalent to a simple `call (far)`.

Also noteworthy is the fact that CPUs often handle the following 3 types of events in a very similar fashion:

- hardware interrupts from I/O devices
- exceptions, errors from code execution (e.g. division by 0, page faults, etc)
- system calls

That makes using something like the `int` instruction a natural choice as your entry and exit points in all of the above handlers would be if not fully then largely identical.